# CSS Selector for table cell with checked input in previous cell

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to select a table cell if the previous cell has a checked input. the I have a sneaking suspicion that this is not possible with CSS, can anybody confirm?

Here is an example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Row with checked input</td>
        <td><input type=checkbox checked /></td>
        <td>should show.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row with unchecked input</td>
        <td><input type=checkbox /></td>
        <td>should be hidden.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And the CSS I tried:

```
td:last-child { display:none; }
input:checked ~ td:last-child { display:initial; }
```

The first selector works to hide unchecked inputs, but then the second selector cannot make the input show up again. I assume the `~` combinator cannot handle children of previous siblings. Is there any way to get around this using CSS, or do I need to use some JavaScript solution?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4P5W/) for those who want a live scratchpad.

Comment: No way to do this in CSS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector

Comment: The `/>` syntax seems really superfluous and strange in the face of unquoted attribute values and `checked` instead of `checked="checked"`.

Comment: @BoltClock that's true, although the /> close was just added by default by my editor. It doesn't bother me so much that I've edited those out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current HTML it is not possible, since CSS cannot look back up to its parent. I.E. The pseudo-selector for the input cannot affect the parent td and following cannot affect the parent's sibling.

If you're flexible with your HTML, you can include the hideable element as a direct sibling inside the same table cell.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Row with checked input</td>
    <td><input type=checkbox checked /><span>should show.</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row with unchecked input</td>
    <td><input type=checkbox /><span>should be hidden.</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
input:not(:checked) + span { display:none; }
```

I threw this in a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MghmU/

Answer (score -1):

This can't be done with just CSS AND have full browser support yet to the best of my knowledge.  So, depending on what browsers you need to support, you will probably need an event listener/handler of some sort to ensure cross-browser compatibility.  You will more than likely want to use a javascript solution.  If you are familiar with jQuery, that would be the easiest way to handle the task.

jQuery(":checked") --> Check out the api [here.](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

You can then write simple functions for .hide and .show.  These can also be found in the api documentation.

The :checked selector is currently only supported by Opera to the best of my knowledge, and according to [W3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_checked.asp)